# how to predict using scikit?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have trained an estimator, called clf,  using fit method and save the model to disk. The next time to run the program , which will load clf from disk.

my problem is :

1. how to predict a sample which saved on disk? I mean, how to load it and predict?
2. how to get the sample label instead of label integer after predict?

Answer (score 2):

1. how to predict a sample which saved on disk? I mean, how to load it and predict?

   You have to use the same array representation for the new samples as the one used for the samples passed to `fit` method. If you want to predict a single sample, the input must be a 2D numpy array with shape `(1, n_features)`.

   The way to read your original file on the HDD and convert it to a numpy array representation suitable for classifier is a domain specific issue: it depends whether you are trying to classify text files, jpeg files, frames in a video file, rows in database, log lines for syslog monitored services...
2. how to get the sample label instead of label integer after predict?

   Just keep a list of label names and ensure that the integer used as target values when fitting are in the range `[0, n_classes)`. For instance `['spam', 'ham']`, if you have predictions in the range `[0, 1]` then you can do:

   ```
   new_samples = # 2D array with shape (n_samples, n_features)
   label_names = ['ham', 'spam']
   predictions = [label_names[pred] for pred in clf.predict(new_samples)]
   ```

Comment: I'm using TfidfVectorizer to generate the array passed to fit method,  e.g. vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf = True, max_df = 0.5, stop_words = 'english',charset_error='ignore')
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(data_train.data), I want to know how to generate the same array representation for the new samples after loading model from disk? I mead, how to generate feature vetor for new sample, because if I just use vectorizer,transform(newSampleData), I think I will get the wrong feature

Comment: You need to reuse the same vectorizer instance and use the transform method. It takes a list of strings as input. Just read your text file with something like (assuming they are encoded with the utf-8 charset):

`new_samples = [open(f, 'wb').read().decode('utf-8') for f in filenames]`

Comment: There is a typo in the previous comment, it should be `open(f, 'rb')` instead of `open(f, 'wb')`.